# Linux set -x when run from a process on Azure

Tags: java, linux, bash, azure, amazon-ec2

I have bash script which sets the environment and runs a java process.
The script calls "set -x".
I have an init.d service which runs a guard java program which does all kinds of guarding tasks including identifying that the process is dead and running the shel that starts it.
On AWS it works perfect.
I moved to azure and the bash script works perfect when run from command line, but doesn't work when run from the guarding java process.
taking down the "set -x" solved it and now it runs also on azure.
Any idea what can cause the issue?
Thanks,
Nir

Answer (score 0):

What is the OS version you are using on Azure. We are not able to reproduce the issue. We also ran a init.d service which runs a sample java program which in turn invokes a shell script which has set -x inside it.

Is set -x important for you to run your script?, because all it does is provide a verbose of each statement that is being executed in your script.

Comment: The version of the azure server (the one with the issue) is 6.4. On AWS it was 5.4. I removed the "set -x", but still I want to understand the reason for the issue.

Comment: I am assuming you are using Oracle Linux 6.4?

Comment: On AWS it was Oracle but on azure it is Centos

Comment: We tried this on CentOS, but could not reproduce the issue. Is this the Guard Java program that you are using: https://github.com/infospace/guard-java

Comment: no it is something I wrote which uses RunTime.getRunTime.exec("sh myscript.sh")

Comment: I used below to run my script:                                                         ProcessBuilder pb =
new ProcessBuilder("myscript.sh");
Process p = pb.start();                                                                                          That worked fine for me on centos. Can you try without sh like this: RunTime.getRunTime.exec("myscript.sh");